# CSS span like a button

Tags: css, button

I have a problem with a `<span>` that I want to look like a "clickfunnels" button.

The button looks super good but when I resize the window screen (or open it in mobile), I can't maintain the look and feel of that button when I resize it.

Here you have the button:

[image]

The website is http://ivandebenito.com/cads/ so you can look at the CSS code.

Comment: Is time to learn responsive and media queries, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to do this? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and **the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your custom CSS if you want to avoid line break :

```
.btn.btn-cta {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

or add this code to maintain line break but more beautifull:

```
.btn.btn-cta {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default span element have inline display.
When screen size reduces it tries to maintain it inline property. That's why buttons overlaps. If you want to make it compatible with mobile devices. In media query section of mobile device of your css file change the display of span element from inline to block. If you do not know about media query you can search about it on google.